Windows and Hyper-V: the boot loader did not load an operating system
On Windows 11 Pro (last version), I've created a virtual disk with Disk2vhd (options vhdx and shadow copy) which is a copy of my C disk. I can mount it (D disk on the image) where EFI partition is visible.
Virtual disk
I've created a Virtual computer with Hyper-V using the previous disk (which was no more mounted), generation 2.
Virtual computer
I can start it, there is no error message.
Virtual computer started
When I connect to it, I get an error message.
Error message when connecting to virtual computer
Remark : I've no ISO of Windows System as it was alredy installed when I bought the PC
What do I miss? Thank you for any support

hi I try with generation 1, the start seems to be successful but I can not do anything in the VM window; the cursor is blinking but no access from the keyboard nor the mouse

Finally, the issue came from the creation of the virtual disk. I did it again including all the necessary partitions and now it is OK.

We all could benefit from a complete description of what was missing. Keep in mind that although you're encouraged to answer your own question, your answer must follow the same community quality standards.

Hi, I think the first creation of the virtual disk was incorrect (I don't know the reason why). What I can say, the format of the EFI partition was "unkown" and I discovered this thank to the software AOMEI Partition Assistant, free version. So I deleted the virtual disk, recreate it and that time the partition was OK.

So please add those parts by [edit]ing the answer. This isn't a forum.
